# Solutions of a linear system

Tags: matrices

$$A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 2 & 1 \\
        1 & 3 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

If $b = [ 2, 4 ,6 ]^T$ , how many solutions are
there to the system $Ax = b$?

My guess is infinitely many because the echelon form produces last row to 0's but not sure

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you agument your matrix as follows:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 4\\
1 & 3 & 2 & 6\\
\end{bmatrix}

For your row reduced echelon form:

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}

The last row shows us we have a free variable.  Call it $z$.  Then our second row shows us that $y+z=2$ and our first row shows us that $x-z=0$.  Or, $y=2-z$ and $x=z$.

Comment: I slapped an x column with random values such as all 1's and then I got the last row as 0's. Does that mean that $x^3$ and $x^4$ are just some value T? meaning infinite many solutions?  I'm not sure if that is the right answer

Comment: Consider the reduced form.  Because of that last row of 0s we see that $z=z$.  This means that $y=2-z$ and $x=z$.